# Difference Between Horizon Commands

Tags: horizon

What is the difference between the following Horizon commands:

- `horizon`
- `horizon db reingest`
- `horizon db backfill`
- `horizon db rebase`

Answer (score 3):

`horizon` - standard operation mode, ingest new ledgers from stellar core, in order.

`horizon db reingest` - perform (re)ingestion on all ledgers that horizon has previously ingested from elder to current. This will replace the old ingested data with new ingested data. When finished, will continue in standard operation mode.

`horizon db backfill <N>` - same as `reingest` but in reverse order, starting from latest ledger, `N` ledgers back.

`horizon db rebase` - clear the history and ingest the latest contiguous segment of ledgers available from stellar core.